# Blender EEVEE not rendering smoke simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation, volumetrics, eevee-render-engine

For some reason the EEVEE viewport is actually rendering the smoke simulation, however, on the actual render, it does not seem to render it at all as if it's excluding it.

I have checked Volumetrics on, so I'm quite stumped here.

Comment: Besides Volumetrics turned on, you also need to add smoke material (to the Domain object). And it must be Principled Volume Shader (not another Volume shader).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you **add the Principled Volume shader to the Volume *not Surface*** in the Material on the Smoke **Domain** (not the emitter), that did it for me

[image: Smoke Material]

If that doesn't work compare your system to the *F3->'Quick Smoke'* with a cube selected

Answer (score 1):

[image]

So I think I solved the problem here.
I been having this problem since morning today. I just realised that in Blender once the animation player passes the end frame mentioned in the cache settings, it disappears in the render.
If the animation is in between Frame start and End frame mentioned in cache settings while baking, the smoke appears in the render. This worked for me. Do check this out and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to use Principled Volume shader in Mantaflow Domain
2. If you render (with camera), in RENDER PROPERTIES > VOLUMETRIC, check the distance (START and END) for 'volumetric' , it depends on your scene, in my case it appear when use 500m but not visible with 9999m
   [image]

if you see the smoke in camera view then it will also will appear when you render it

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you use a custom domain for some reason in the *Object* tab (the little orange box, upper the modifier tab) the *Domain* is not checked in the *Visibility > Render*.